# How to add html form user input into a file with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how do I put HTML form user input into a file using JavaScript ONLY.
I have struggled to find an answer to such a simple question.

Comment: .... like write to an external file? Or the same file?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i mean Gnuey, an Externeal file.

Comment: To a local file on the user's computer or a file on the server?

Comment: A file on the server.

Comment: But are you using some form of JavaScript server-side?

Comment: [This could help you out. Digged out on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795357/javascript-in-html-write-to-file)

Comment: No i am not useing JavaScript server-side... I am not quite sure how to use it server-side :(

Answer (score 2):

Writing data to files on a local filesystem is only supported in modern browsers with a set of limitations, you can google for HTML FileSystem API.

As for writing to a file, this is a basic example:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {

  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
        console.log('Write completed.');
      };

      fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
      };

      // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
      var blob = new Blob(['Lorem Ipsum'], {type: 'text/plain'});

      fileWriter.write(blob);

    }, errorHandler);

  }, errorHandler);

}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

Comment: Sorry, It isn't working.  Thank you for trying to help though :)

Comment: @LittleProgrammer, when someone makes a big effort writing a high quality answer, cant you at least mention in what ways its not working?

Comment: No worries, I just know the feeling when your answers are dismissed without an explanation. I see now that the effort maybe wasn't as big as I thought, as it was an example pasted from somewhere :) I was on my phone before and didn't read properly. Obviously you'd have to adapt his example to your situation, but if things break simply by including his code I guess it's a bad sign.

Comment: yes, this is a basic piece of code, which I took on the Internet, but it is easily adaptable.