# PHPESSID on browser

Tags: php

I have a script that runs into a virtual market website.

My script searchs for a specified item and then he buys it if the price is below "X" number. But sometimes my script stop running because the ppsessid number gets updated on the browser and I need to fill it manually on my "cookies.txt".

Is there any solution to make an automatic script which could update automatically the phpsessid number so my script will have access everytime into the website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Comment: By [setting the maximum session lifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) to something over 24 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your rather incomplete question, i would use this function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

If thats not what youre searching for, please clarify your problem.