# JS download file from server, and send Authorization header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download, filesystems, client-side

I have a little problem that I can't figure out how to fix. I need to send my server a request with custom headers, download it to the client, and prompt a save alert of the browser.

I use AngularJS. I downloaded all the bits of the file, and I have its name. Now I need to let the client save it to his computer. Any ideas on doing it without server modification?

Here's how I download a file:

```
Documents.download(id).$promise.catch(function(response) {
    switch(response.status) {
        case '412':
            toaster.pop({
                type: 'error',
                title: LOCALIZATION.errors.downloadingPC.title,
                body: LOCALIZATION.errors.downloadingPC.message
                    });
            break;
        default:
            toaster.pop({
                type: 'error',
                title: LOCALIZATION.errors.general.title,
                body: LOCALIZATION.errors.general.message
            });
            break;
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    // the file downloaded. I have the bits of it. now what?
})
```

Comment: can you show us some of the code you got so far? It also helps to understand your goal. thanks.

Comment: @gioravered I added the code. There's a factory which begins the download process. once its done, I need to prompt a save alert with the browser.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "I Have the bits of it"

Comment: @gioravered I mean that I successfully received the file's content.

Comment: All the bits that the file contain downloaded. Now I want to ask the client to download it to his computer.

Comment: Oh - Ok, so I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21012689/2649154) answer says it all