# Modifying Text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have data written to a text file in javascript. I want it to write a username and password to the text file and create a new line every time. Here is my code http://pastebin.com/24Tvdemu.

Can anyone help this has had me stumped for ages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Create and save file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Answer (score 0):

As Javascript in html is a client side language, you will need to send the files to the server, and save there the file. Anyway, you can prompt the user to save the file in their local machine, but it´s not usefull at least you really need that for any reason.

Check this answer [Javascript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions for this -

1. If you are trying to write a file on client machine, You can't do this in any cross-browser way. IE does have methods to enable "trusted" applications to use ActiveX objects to read/write file.
2. If you are trying to save it on your server then simply pass on the text data to your server and execute the file writing code using some server side language.
3. To store some information on the  client side that is considerably small, you can go for cookies.
4. Using the HTML5 API for Local Storage.

More details : **[Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript/21012689#21012689)**