# How to log selected markers in Google fusion table map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

My fusion table map contains about 5000 markers. I want to generate lists of selected markers. The simplest way to do this would seem te be to click on the relevant markers, and then write the IDs of these markers to a logfile. I think I should be able to use a variation on [this blob/upload technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript/21016088#21016088), but I can't see exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further consideration, I decided that the simplest answer is to accumulate the IDs in an empty DIV:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) { 
  newValue=document.getElementById('album').innerHTML  + ':' + e.row['Bestand'].value;
  document.getElementById('album').innerHTML=newValue;
  });
```

This is just what I needed (called for help too soon?).