# is there a way to create file and write data to it using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to create and write data to a file using javascript/jquery. I referred this link https://gist.github.com/Arahnoid/9925725#file-read-write-file-js . But it gives me error for tis line

```
var file = new File("E:/abc/sample.txt); 
 error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: in firefox
```

Comment: JS (unless used on the server, *node.js*) doesn't have access to the file system. So, No.

Comment: not using a browser as the client

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Comment: @tymeJV Does not the last Javascript Api provide some simple ways for accessing filesystem?

Comment: @reporter The [File APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/getAsText) are now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You can't write files in javascript using your browser without asking the user for permission first.

you can prompt the user to save a file using the following liberary:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

POC code:

```
<script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
<script>
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
</script>
```

This will prompt the user to save "Hello world!" to the file "Hello, world.txt" file.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client side language which runs on server, and it doesn't have access to client file system, I don't know what your exact requirement is but this might help you

http://tutorialzine.com/2011/05/generating-files-javascript-php/
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Would you let me know what is your exact requirement then I might help you

Comment: i want to introduce a save as draft feature in my form. hence i thought of having a button as draft on click of which it converts the form data to json and i would write this json data to a file on some server . Later when the user wishes to continue filling the remaining form i thought i could read the saved json data and populate the html form fields.

Comment: That is quite simple thing you don't need to write it on file for this.. You could save JSON string on user's localStorage variable and can use it from there.
Another option is of saving information in cookies, For you requirement I would suggest you to use localStorage, As it is supported by all major browsers and it is quite straight forward

______   you can have a look at this link for more information http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp and google it for localstorage