# How to write data in text file using Javascript/JQuery without ActiveXObject as it supports only IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one file i.e style.css/any file whose content need to be shifted to another text file which is file.txt. Using ActiveXObject is not working, so could you please provide any other solution.?

Here is my code which I tried.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.get('css/style.css', function (data) {
      //  alert(data);
        writeToFile(data);
    });

    function writeToFile(content) {
      //  alert(content);
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("file.txt", 8);
        fh.WriteLine(content);
        fh.Close();

    }
});
```

Comment: You have a couple of options, the easiest option would be plain HTML5 and Javascript. https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/     Also your question sounds very demanding maybe change it a bit

Comment: Why? Whatever you are trying to do it sounds like you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Comment: I believe this is an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - also your ActiveX would likely work in an HTA

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
`window.location = "data:text/html," + yourData`

It'll dump the data in the url and force a download of the data.