# how to write value of javascript in text file in mvc5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to write a Javascript's value in text file in my mvc5 project. Is it possible to do so?I tried the code below but didn't succeed. its not considering the "OpenTextFile" and ActiveXObject as a function. do i need to add some references for using these?

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("data.txt", 8, false, 0);
fh.WriteLine(d1 + ',' + d2);
fh.Close();
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Comment: You could try using the FileInfo type and StreamWriter to manage those tasks.