# How to save a large json object to file?

Tags: angularjs

Just started with angular and I am debugging my angular app and would like to save a large json object. Is it possible to save this in chrome? Or how to save this with angular?
Extra info: I want to save the contents of $rootScope to a json file.

Comment: Define exactly what you mean by *"to file"*. You could store it in [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) but if you actually want to write the contents to a file, you'll *probably* need a server-side component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

Comment: your question is nebulous, please be more specific.

Comment: is that specific enough?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from your question where you want to save the file so I'll assume server side you could post the json to a rest service using $post (a get request will probably be too long) on the server that writes the file with the posted contents.

Comment: Save on my local machine, I just want to use the contents as a mockfile.

Comment: Why not just do a console.log(myjson) and copy an paste in to a file. Or using angular binding throw a temporary {{myjson | json}} binding on the page. Adding the pipe Jason on the page will writ out the object in json notation.

Comment: it just says : $SCOPE when I use {{rootScope|json}}

Answer (score 0):

You should use the browser tools from your favorite browser.  in your code write this code:

```
// .. 
var json = JSON.stringify($rootScope);
console.log(json);
```

You will be able to copy the content from the `console` and you can save it into a new text file.

Comment: getting an error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON