# Generate TSV file given the table headers in javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

Is it possible, using javascript, to generate a TSV file on the browser side given that I have an array of headers that I want to put in the file?

For example, in my javascript I have:

```
var fields = ["field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"];
```

Can I create a TSV file which contains the following in the first line

```
field1      field2      field3      field4      field5
```

and save it as "fields.tsv"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `\t` or `\t\t` to join `fields` array values single or multiple `tab` characters; use `data URI` with `MIME` type set to `text/tab-separated-values` with joined array concatenated , set `window.location.href` or `window.open()` first parameter to `data URI` to initiate `Save File` dialog.

Edit, Updated

As noted by @Eugene, pass joined `fileds` array to `encodeURIComponent()` to preserve tab characters

```js
var fields = ["field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"];
var tsv = fields.join("\t");
window.location.href = "data:text/tab-separated-values," + encodeURIComponent(tsv);
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ehfbwS4UWdLiM350rx1i?p=preview

Comment: Make sure to add ```encodeURIComponent(tsv)``` so tabs are not stripped away

Answer (score 0):

Based from the suggestions and the 2nd answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript) I have come to this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6G00ghEDnzytDWe9wgta?p=preview) solution. :)

```
function createFile () {
    var fields = ["field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"];
    var tsv = fields.join("\t");
    var generatedFile = makeTextFile(tsv);
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadLink');
    link.href = generatedFile;
};
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Why do you set `download` attribute value to `.txt` if requirement is to create a `text/tab-separated-values` file?

Comment: The `tsv` file generated will be opened via Microsoft Excel and Excel saves tab-delimited files with a `.txt` extension that's why I'm saving it as `.txt` for consistency.