# Exporting HTML Table to Excel for IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am trying to create a JavaScript function that will export a HTML table to Excel. The code below works in Chrome, but in IE, I receive a popup saying *"No apps are installed to open this type of link (data)."* I need the export to happen on the client and using ActiveXObject is not an option. Any help on making this work in both IE and Chrome would be greatly appreciated.

```
var uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,"
var template = "<!DOCTYPE html><html  xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'> " +
                   "<head> " + 
                   "   <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html;charset=windows-1252'><meta name=Generator content='Microsoft Excel 11'> " +
                   "   <meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet> <meta name=Generator content='Microsoft Excel 11'> " +
                   "<style> " +
                   "<!--table @page{}-->" +
                   "</style>" +
                   "<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>  <x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name>    <x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes> " +
                   "</x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--> " +
                   "</head>" +
                   "<body><form method='POST' action='PRJEdetail-ClientExportTest.asp' name='frmExcel'></form>" +
                   tableHTML +
                   "</body>" +
               "</html>"
var base64 = function (s) { return   window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
window.location.href = uri + base64(template)
```

Comment: this question is answered here check 2nd answer for solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Comment: Are you referring to passing data to the server for processing? I've tried this, but some of my tables to export are large and I run into data limit issues when trying to pass the data to the server. That is why I'm trying to find a client side solution.

Comment: No if you check solutions there they are generating export files using JS in browser. in second answer they provided a IE specific answer as well.

Comment: Do you mean the solution posted by Useless Code using Blob?

Comment: no, solution provided by Lifecube, Useless's code only export plain text files. but you can merge both and create a better solution for your self

Comment: Unfortunately, my table is still proving to be too large. I think I'll have to save the data to a file, pass the file name to the server, and then process the file from there. I was hoping I could find a more straightforward solution. Thanks anyhow.