# How to dump json data into json file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have unformatted data in my data.json file. I have formatted it using javascript. Now I have to dump formatted data into newData.json file. But I am not able to find correct code. Please suggest how can I dump json data into newData.json file.

```
 $.getJSON( "movie.json", function( data ) {
var result = {
    Win: {},
    Nominated: {}
};

data.forEach( obj => {
    var stats = result[obj.WinType][obj.Nominee] = result[obj.WinType][obj.Nominee] || {
        count: 0,
        rating: 0,
        0: 0,
        name: obj.Nominee
    };
    stats.rating += obj.RATING;
    stats.count++;
    stats[0] += obj.WinProbability * 100;
});

Object.keys(result).forEach( grp =>
    result[grp] = Object.keys(result[grp]).map( name => {
        var stats = result[grp][name];
        stats[0] /= 100;
        stats[1] = Math.round(stats.rating * 100 / stats.count) / 100;
        delete stats.count;
        delete stats.rating;
        return stats;
    })
);
console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Comment: Did you write any code yet ? Can you show what you've done so far ? Are you trying to do this on server or browser ?

Comment: @PamioSolanky I have added code please check

Comment: @dhanashri you want the JSON file to be downloadable by the user?

Comment: @dhanashri is it is not for the user & for some of your own site purpose then just post the JSON to some server side code file & you can use file handling to write it in the filel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have your new data into the `results` variable.

You could write the results to a new file and download the same. But you can't write the data to a file on your server. If you need to write data to server then you will have to create an api which gets the data on the server and then it writes the same into a new file which will then be available for you to access from browser just like the file 'movie.json'

Approach 1:

```
var result = {'your new data'}
var url = 'data:text/json;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(result);
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

This will allow you to download the file with the new data.

Approach 2:

You have an API written on server that expects JSON data which will write to a file in the public directory so its available on client.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/api/new_data',
  data: result,
  success: function(){console.log('success')}
});
```

This is an example of how it can be done. You will have to write your own api to accept the POST request and write to a file.

Hope it helps.