# How to write to a file using angularJS2?

Tags: angular

I am new to angularJS2 and i have a requirement to write the user input into a file. I have a little understanding that it is not possible with angularJS2 as it is running on the client side, am i right? can anyone let me know on how to write the input from the user to a local file, is there any angularJS2 library or is there any way where in we can use the node.js command into the angularJS2 component and write to a local file

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Writing a file is a server-side operation. You need a back-end. For example Node.js.

Package for node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile