# Resend body from response exactly as it comes

Tags: javascript, http

I'm using a 3rd party API Rest which returns the contents of a file in the body. This file can be text or binary (pdf, docx).

For security reasons I need to use an intermediate API Rest as a bridge between my frontend app and this 3rd party API Rest.

What I want is to be able to return the exact same body that I get from the 3rd party to my frontend app, because at the moment as I get the body and build a new response in my intermediate API I'm somehow modifying something.

This is what I do in my intermediate API:

```
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: `${api}`,
  headers: { OTCSTICKET: ticket}
}

rp(options)
  .then(parsedBody => res.status(201).send(parsedBody))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).send({ msg: 'download error', err }));
```

I would need to send exactly the same body that I get in the response. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Formatting the code pointed out a missing closing \`, you should check if it is also missing in your code, and if not fix it in the question.

Comment: fixed in the question; the original code is fine, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting binary content in Node.js using request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855015/getting-binary-content-in-node-js-using-request)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to get this working, so I'll post here in case it helps someone.

This thread gave me the solution
[Getting binary content in Node.js using request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855015/getting-binary-content-in-node-js-using-request)

So I just set the encoding to null and I passed as body the one I got from the 3rd party API

```
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: `${api}`,
  headers: { OTCSTICKET: ticket},
  encoding: null,
  resolveWithFullResponse: true
}

rp(options)
  .then(response => res.status(201).send(response.body))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).send({ msg: 'download error', err }));
```

With this I managed to get this working.