# Basic syntax for File Handling typescript angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file-handling

Can anyone tell me the basic syntax of **how to read and write text file i.e file handling in typescript**. And also if anyone can give me corresponding link I'll be grateful.

Comment: TypeScript is not a language or a library; it's a type layer on top of JavaScript. It provides nothing having anything to do with file handling. Angular is a framework built in TS/JS, and also provides no special file handling capabilities of its own. If your idea is to read and write a local text file, you can't do that in any web application built in any framework in any language.

Comment: As I said, no, if you mean a local file on the machine running the browser running the app. If you want to read and write a text file on the server, there are lots of ways, which are well documented.

Comment: you will have to do it on server.. make api call with whatever data you want to write... understand basics of client vs server plz

Comment: I'm not sure how many times you want me to say **NO**. If you want more hints, you need to carefully describe the exact problem you are trying to solve. Are you trying to read and write a local file from within the app while it is running? You can't do that. Do you want to include the contents of a text file somehow into your app at build time? There are of course ways to do that.

Comment: Ok, can you give any example how to read/write text file on server

Comment: Now you got me. I want to load contents of a text file in my app. I just want to know the basic syntax.

Comment: like: reader = new Reader();
Using this type of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Have a method `readTextFile` in your class. This is totally based on Javascript

```
readTextFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log(allText); // Here is the contents of the file
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

And then call the function with it's path

```
this.readTextFile(path_of_the_file_to_be_read_as_string);
```

in the above line, `this` is based on the place fro where you are calling the function.

We are able to read files with javascript but we can't write into files. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21012689/6554634

Comment: Why don't you simply use angular's http?

Comment: I'm working on **angular 2 forms**. I need to store login data in txt file.
How can I do that?

Comment: And where should I place my txt file? @Mr_Perfect