# Save result of web page to text files

Tags: javascript

The below javascript will open the url in a new tab. I want to save contents of the loaded webpage to a text file. Also after saving I wanted to close the tab. How can i do in java script

```
var newtab = window.open('https://webpage.com');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably consider using a different programming language, and not JavaScript for what you are trying to accomplish.

Read this StackOverflow article regarding writing files with javascript:
[Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

There are security reasons why JavaScript does not allow the method of saving files locally on machines *for the most part* - the primary reason is because that it runs on all browsers and would be a huge security flaw (ie: think of drive-by scripts that could just throw any file on your computer).

Hope this helps.