# Is it possible to update a .txt file in the root directory in a HTML browser when the client presses a button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, aframe

I am currently working on a virtual reality prototype using HTML and aframe.io.

When the client uses the virtual reality prototype, upon clicking on a button in the designer settings, I need a .txt file to be overwritten, which effectively saves the settings decided by the designer.

Hence, I need the .txt file which contains the settings of the web application which is coded in HTML to be updated.

I have tried node.js, jquery and PHP, but nothing works for me. The furthest I have gotten is a .txt file to be downloaded to the "Downloads" folder, which is not the result I want.

What I need is when the button is clicked on the Web Application, a .txt file in the root directory of the HTML Web Application will be overwritten.

Can someone help me out and advise whether this is possible?

Comment: Sounds like you really need need to use cookies, localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or sessionStorage(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit file - pure js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469243/edit-file-pure-js)