# AJAX sucess writing to file but file is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been working on a web page which can't use PHP so I had to look up a solution without. I now have the following jQuery code:

```
function writeFile() {
  alert("writing file...");

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "test.txt", // url of receiver file on server
    data: "test", // your data
    success: alert("sucess writing the file!"), // callback when ajax request finishes
    dataType: "text" // text/json
  });
};
```

The file is where it should be and the `alert()` are showing up (also the `success` alert) but somehow the file is empty. Why?

Comment: Note that the second `alert()` is only showing up because you execute it as soon as the `writeFile()` function is called. It's not actually dependent on the success of the AJAX request. I'd suggest reading the `$.ajax` documentation to see exactly how to provide a handler function to that event. Firstly, check the console to see exactly is happening with the request. Secondly, note that JS cannot write to a file on the server, so I'm not certain what goal you're hoping this logic will achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

Comment: You can download data to a file on the user's PC using javascript, but you cant tell the server to save it, unless the server has a url you can POST to waiting for an action parameter to tell it to write a data parameter to a file - for example.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX cannot directly write to a file, because JavaScript is a client side only and not server side. What you want is a server that catches your AJAX request; server can be anything, including PHP, JAVA or NodeJS. You can only read static files using AJAX but that is all.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's more like a long comment

Comment: You can basically use any server side language, such as java or even javascript in NodeJS which is pretty easy to setup

Answer (score 0):

You can't just write to a text file on the server using client-side AJAX scripting. You will have to use Node.JS or a PHP server-side script to write to the file on the server. This example below uses a PHP script. You will want a file called `test.php` in the same directory as the page the AJAX is on. This will `POST` the string "hello world" to test.php, as the superglobal **`$_POST['textcontent']`**. It is possible, using an anonymous function in the `success` field, to get the output from the PHP script and show it on the page. Note that you can replace "hello world" in the example below, to a `$("#my-input-area").val()` variable, if you want to write user input to a file.

```
function writeFile() {
    alert("writing file...");
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {
            textcontent: "hello world",
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#ajax-area").html(response);
        }
    });
};
```

And then your PHP will look like this.

## `test.php`

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['textcontent'])) {
    file_put_contents("test.txt", $_POST['textcontent']);
    exit("<p>TXT file written successfully!</p>");
}
// This is where you write to the text file.
// The string in the exit() function will appear in your $("#ajax-area")
else {
    exit("<p>No text string submitted.</p>");
}

?>
```

Using the above example, the PHP script will receive the string "hello world" from the AJAX call. This will write to the `test.txt` file in the same directory as your PHP script, which would be in the same directory as the page with the AJAX. You can put these in a different folder on the server if you want. Anything the PHP script outputs, either with `echo` or with `exit`, will be returned as the `response` parameter, in your `success` function in your AJAX call.

I hope any of this helps.