# How to set data into JSON file using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

$.getJSON let us to get data from the file, is there any way to set data into the file? i have tried $.setJSON, but it shows me "$.setJSON is not a function".

Comment: ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016088/9007957

Comment: You mean accessing the local files ?

Comment: i created a web application using visual studio, and i want to retrieve and update the json file (data.json). record.html and data.json file is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the local file system using front-end Javascript. And there is no way on doing it.

What you can do is create a web server. 
Send a request with the data in the server using AJAX
On the server, save the data by writing it on a file

That's pretty much it.

Comment: i think that is not true, because i can access the local file system and retrieve the content in the data.json.

Comment: Based on what you want, what I mean is, you can't write to a file using front-end JS.

Comment: You can access a selected file using an input `type=file` so this answer is wrong. You can't write a file, that is right.

Comment: so, if i use ajax to pass data to .cs file, is it allow me to save the data to data.json file?

Comment: .cs (CSharp) is out of context here. What I am trying to say is, we use AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) to post our data to the server (in whatever language it may be written) and save it there in a file