# How do you modify a file using JavaScript together with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to add text to a text document using JavaScript and PHP. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by using Javascript (front-end) to send an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) request to the PHP server script that does the operation (back-end).

What you can do is use `jQuery.ajax` or `XMLHttpRequest`.

## [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

```js
var url = "addtext.php"; // Your URL here
var data = {
  text: "My Text"
}; // Your data here

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

## [`jQuery.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```js
var url = "addtext.php"; // Your URL here
var data = {
  text: "My Text"
}; // Your data here

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  method: "POST"
})
```

Note: There is also the [`jQuery.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method, but I have not included it.

And, in the PHP file, with the necessary permissions, you can write to the file using [`fwrite`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) in combination with the other file functions.

```php
<?php
$text = $_POST["text"]; // Gets the 'text' parameter from the AJAX POST request

$file = fopen('data.txt', 'a'); // Opens the file in append mode.
fwrite($file, $text); // Adds the text to the file
fclose($file); // Closes the file
?>
```

If you want to open the file in a different mode, there is [a list of modes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) on the PHP website.

All the filesystem functions can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) on the PHP website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can append to a text document unless you are writing server side code.

There are some possible workarounds mentioned in this post:
[Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)