# Javascript app: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs, stringify

I have an array and I want to create a .json to store the array in it. This is what I have, but i receive `require is not defined`. I know it has something to do with NodeJS, but I dont know what I should do.

```
let answersString = JSON.stringify(answersArray);
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync("answers.json", answersString);
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Now I know this was a pretty dumb question, sorry. In the meantime I learned about node, bundling, testing etc.

Comment: Is this to do with RequireJS, which is a browser framework? Node.JS runs server-side, not in the browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the code in client, and `require()` does not exists in javascript browser-side (nodeJS is server side...).

My proposal would be to send file to server side where you will have `fs` and do the work there.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. And how should I create the .json file?

Answer (score 0):

You still can use require at the client side but you need to use a bundler. The notorious ones are Webpack and Browserify.

Comment: Yes, now I know all this. 