# Unable to export API Response in Text format to CSV file

Tags: javascript, postman, web-api-testing, export-csv

I have a API which sends response in Text format as follows:

```
"521942","556463745.63","11/1/2016 12:00:00 AM","0","11/1/2016 12:00:00 AM" 
"521942","17848781.34","11/1/2016 12:00:00 AM","0","5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM" 
"521942","8038249.48","11/1/2016 12:00:00 AM","0","5/18/2015 12:00:00 AM"
```

I need to export this response into a CSV file but I am not able to do so. 
I tried using the File Object Method:

```
var filename = "abc"; 
var outFilePath = 'C:\\Users\\archit.goyal\\Downloads\\' + filename + '.csv'; 
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody); 
var file = new File({writetofile: new File(outFilePath).write(ReportCSV)});
```

But this method is throwing error:

> There was an error in evaluating the test script: ReferenceError: File is not defined

Please take a look into this issue and suggest.

Comment: Looks like it might be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Comment: If you're trying to do that all within the Postman UI (From the example in the question you are) - I've sure it doesn't actually provide that functionality. I might be wrong.