# Write data from text file, javascript, google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-files

There are a lot of solutions to this that only work in IE (using ActiveX), but is there any way to write a text file using Javascript and Chrome?

EX (put name in txt file):

```
function myFunction(){
//code to add name to .txt file
}


<p> Enter name </p>
<input type=text id=name>
<input type=button value=submit onclick='myFunction()'>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)