# Redirecting after onclick()-event with a-tag

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am programming an app with elecrtonjs and got stuck.

So on my page there is this HTML:

```
<a href="./step1.html" id="next"><span onclick="writeToFile();return false">Next ></span></a`>
```

And in the javasriptfile I am saving stuff to a file in the directory:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function writeToFile() {
    //alert(document.getElementsByTagName("input").length);
    var text = "";
    // Change the content of the file as you want
    // or either set fileContent to null to create an empty file
    for (var i = document.getElementsByTagName("input").length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        text += document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].getAttribute("name")+":\n";
        text += document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value+"\n";
    }

    // The absolute path of the new file with its name
    var filepath = "mynewfile.txt";
    fs.appendFile(filepath, text, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("The file was succesfully saved!");
    });
 }
```

The code redirects properly but does not append the user-input in to the specified file.

Am I timing the stuff wrong? I tried

```
onbeforeunload
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can use window.location.href="./step1.html" after writeToFile finishes instead of <a> tag

Comment: Maybe this link could help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Answer (score 0):

As **Chris Li** already stated, you should use

```
window.location.href = "./step1.html"
```

and remove the href field of your link.