# Browser-based JS database

Tags: javascript, database

I'm working on a little side project and wanted to keep it as simple as possible.
So app will have no back end, it will just be a single html page with some local javascript included that can be passed around and run locally.

Given those requirements, I'm looking for a some sort of solution that would let me store and load data like you would a database, in a way the data can be permanently stored in a file. So preferably, being able to  use a json file like a NoSQL database.

I've looked at `lowdb`, `alasql`, and `lokijs`, but none of those seem to meet my requirements. They either need a node server to function, or only use local storage or memory to store data.

Comment: You could try [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). Probably want to use a library that makes its use a bit easier. Would still have to load a file but could store it in local IDB while its in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (except with an ugly workaround).

Such an application would require JavaScript to read/write from disk while running inside a webpage in a browser, and it's not technically possible. This has nothing to do with the file format.

However...

The workaround is to keep all the data in a JSON file, then load it dinamically via JavaScript (for example, with [drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop)). Then when you need to save it... you allow the modified JSON [to be downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016088/6923555), and once downloaded you'd replace the old JSON with this new one, manually.

Comment: oof, guess I didn't realize how restricted js was when it comes to files

Comment: @SpeedOfRound It's not really JavaScript as a language, it's the platform (the browser). You can use JavaScript and write a Node.js app which has normal read/write access to files, for example.