# How can I read file content with react-dropzone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm trying to learn more about working with files for an upcoming project. Is there a way with react-dropzone that I can run a function when onDrop happens to change the contents of the files I'm uploading? For example, if I'm uploading a word doc that says "Hi everybody" how would I change the content to "Hi Dr. Nick"?

I've tried just accessing the data by using the filereader api after before attempting to make the changes. I tried using filereader right after the opening curly bracket of the async function and wasn't able to get it to work.

```
import React from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const FileUpload = ({
    children, disableClick, channelId, mutate, style = {},
}) => (
    <Dropzone
        style={style}
        className="ignore"
        onDrop={async ([file]) => {
            const response = await mutate({
                variables: {
                    channelId,
                    file,
                },
            });
            console.log(response);
        }}
        disableClick={disableClick}
    >
        {children}
    </Dropzone>
);

const createFileMessageMutation = gql`
  mutation($channelId: Int!, $file: File) {
    createMessage(channelId: $channelId, file: $file)
  }
`;

export default graphql(createFileMessageMutation)(FileUpload);
```

Any thoughts on how to access and modify the contents of the file are greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
onDrop={async ([file]) => {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result;
    displayContents(contents);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}}
```

What you can do on frontend is to read file content and display it, all manipulations with file content should be done on server side. Push your file using ajax to your server with list of informations you want to change and use for example in nodeJS `fs = require('fs')`to make file modifications.

Also please visit this post i see that guys provided some solutions for your problem:

[Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

and here is a fidlle taken from above link: http://jsfiddle.net/o4rhg1xe/1/

In Summary, you can read text file content using code i have provided and then use method from link to create Blob object with content you want and such file can be downlaoded by browser, (see fiddle)

Still in my opinion file modifications shoudl be moved to back-end side, ans i cant see no usecase to make them on frontend side.