# Can JavaScript save values without PHP?

Tags: javascript

I am begginer in programming. I have made these stopwatch for speedsolves using HTML and JavaScript.
Is there any way of saving my average solve time using Javascript only?
For instance i have some variable with loop:

```js
var time=0;
if (true){
  time++;
}
```

and after I **close the HTML site**, **close the browser** and **turn off the computer**, after opening the site again I want to get  `var time=value before closing the site`
I'm familiar with PHP and databases, but I dont really want to use it, since I have to start a server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to save data for your program to read later, you can use localStorage or sessionStorage. That is, `localStorage.setItem('name', 'value')` and `localStorage.getItem('name')` to read it. (They're the same, except sessionStorage gets cleared once the browser is closed, while localStorage doesn't.)

To actually save a file, you can do that only by triggering it to be downloaded. First you create a Blob with the content you want for the file, then you get an object URL for that Blob. Assign the URL to the href of a link with a "download" attribute and click it.

```
function saveFile(contents, name) {
  const blob = new Blob([contents], {type: 'text/plain'});
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = name;
  link.href = url;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little more information will help, but, as you are talking of storage, you can use localstorage or sessionstorage within javascript to store the values.

Comment: I have used localstorage like you all recommended me to and it did the trick. You were right about the lack of information, so I have edited the question a little. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For saving files on the local device, you can use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/). But in your situation, an easier solution would be to take advantage of `localstorage`.

Note: From what I've found, LocalStorage won't work without a server. So if you want to store data and aren't using a server, FileSaver may work better. Then again, I don't know if it's possible to load the data in a file saved in FileSaver into javascript in a browser, especially if you don't have a server

Comment: What browser did you test that in? In Firefox at least, local files are more than capable of using localStorage.