# Add new object to JSON array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, backend

I have  `product.json`, `admin.html` and a `admin.js` files.
My goal is to add new products in JSON through an admin page, JSON is used in my website to show a list of products.

**NOTE:** I only want to add objects in json from client side, I've made a e-commerce website which lists all the product and a admin panel login to add more products, so nothing is serverside and will be done locally.

The JSON contains an array of objects, like:

```
[
  {
    "company": "xyz",
    "item": "shirt",
    "price": 100,
    "discount": 10%
  }
]
```

I have to add more objects in JSON through an admin page which contains a html form, like:

```
  <form>
  <h3>Company</h3>
        <input type="text" id="campany" placeholder="enter company name">
        <h3>Item</h3>
        <input type="text" id="item" placeholder="enter item name">
        <h3>Price</h3>
        <input type="text" id="price" placeholder="enter price">
        <h3>Discount</h3>
        <input type="text" id="discount" placeholder="enter disc.">
    </form>

    <button onclick="show()" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

The js file is like:

```
const obj = fetch("json/products.json")

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
var addObj;

function show()
{

     addObj =
      `{"campany": "${campany.value}",
    "item": "${item.value}",
    "price": ${price.value},
    "discount": "${discount.value}%"},`

    myJSON = myJSON + addObj;
    console.log(obj); 

}
obj.push(addObj);
```

I'm new to js and dealing with JSON for the first time, all the other related answers are not helping me and I can't find the right things in the docs.
I hope I'm clear with my goal, please help me.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Appending the new object to the 'JSON' array or writing the JSON object back to a file? If it's the second case, then does this answer your question: [Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

Comment: obj.push(addObj)

Comment: @BillyBrown I want to add a new object in my json

Comment: @AbhinnKrishn add the object to your json, but not save the json file?

Comment: @BillyBrown no, i want to save the new object in json, I want to use the new objects at other place.

Comment: @AbhinnKrishn you need to make sure to use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) correctly (as suggested by @Gillespie59), and then not treat your JSON as a string: it will be parsed to JavaScript, and from there you can use it as a JavaScript array. If you want to then save the new JSON back to the file, then as @Evgeniy said, you will need a server and a server-side language for this (this can be done with JavaScript in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)). You may also encounter some security/CORS errors when reading local files from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = fetch("json/products.json")

function show()
{

 let addObj =
  `{"campany": "${campany.value}",
   "item": "${item.value}",
   "price": ${price.value},
   "discount": "${discount.value}%"},`

   obj.push(addObj);
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25765382)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to edit JSON-file. So, as you know, JS work only on client-side. So, if you need to edit file, you should probably use PHP or something else that working on servere-side, where your file is located

Comment: I want to add an object to my json.

Answer (score 0):

fetch is an asynchrounous method, using promise object.

```
let obj;
fetch("json/products.json")
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(body => obj = body);
```