# I have this code, I want to take the input from the user and then save it to my device locally as .txt file from HTML Input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is my code until now, which does not contain any means of saving the input locally.

The purpose of the code is to take questions from the user as input and then saving it locally in a .txt, then I solve the question and send them the answer personally.

*This code is not meant to be used online. This is to be used locally!!*

What can I do in this to save the input in a .txt file?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> CodeHelper - Python </title>
        <link rel="icon" href="Logo.png" type="image/x icon"></link>
    </head>
    <style>
        @font-face{
            font-family: SaltyOcean;
            src: url(SaltyOcean.woff);
        }
        * {
            text-align: center;
        }
        body{
            background-color: darkgray;
            background-image: url(BACK_1.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;;
        }
        .main_heading {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: SaltyOcean;
            color: wheat;
            opacity: 1;
            margin-top: 10vh;
            font-size: 64px;
        }
        .main{
            background-color: rgba(169,169,169,0.3);
        }
        .URL_Input, .Next {
            font-size:1.3em;
            padding:5px 10px;
            font-family: SaltyOcean;
            }
        .URL_Input {
            border-radius:4px 0px 0px 4px;
            width:30em;
            text-align: left;
            border:2px solid #EEEEEE;
            background: #EEEEEE;
            outline:none;
        }
        .URL_Input:focus {
            border:2px solid #0485ff;
        }
        .Next {
            border-radius:0px 4px 4px 0px;
            border:2px solid #0485ff;
            background: #0485ff;
            color:white;
            box-align: centre;
        }
        .hr_bottom{
            color: wheat;
            margin-top: 10vh;
        }
        .created_by{
            font-family: SaltyOcean;
            font-size: 32px;
            color: wheat;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <img src="Logo.png"></img>
        <div class="main">
            <h1 class='main_heading'> Help With Code in Python ! </h1>
        </div>
        <form method="POST">
        <input type='text' class='URL_Input' placeholder="Enter the question/program to be asked here..."></input>
        <button class='Next' type="" onclick="">Send</button>
        </form>
        <hr class="hr_bottom"></hr>
        <h5 class='created_by'>Created by Bhavyadeep</h5>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works correctly until now. I just want to how to do this.

Comment: You can't or should not use files locally in javascript for security reasons

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't or should not use files locally in javascript for security reasons Browser-side Javascript doesn't have permission to write to the user PC.