# Log Form inputs to a txt file?

Tags: html, forms, web

I am looking at making a simple survey for my clients, I have the base code, I just need to be able to log the users input to a txt file!

```
<html xmlns="">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Form validation example</title>
  <style>
    input{display:block; margin-bottom:10px;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>######</h1>
  <h2>#####</h2>

  <form action="validation_example.html" method="post">
    <label for="first_name">#####</label>
    <input id="first_name" type="text" />
    
    <label for="last_name">###</label>
    <input id="last_name" type="text" />
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Comment: thanks, but not really what I am looking for

Comment: Then give more explanations of what exactly you want to do, and in which text file you want to put the data, and how you want to do it.

Comment: 1 answer per line, just a simple quiz for my clients/members

Comment: Can you clarify how do you plan to serve this html? Are you using a web server to handle the form data? If yes, which framework/language are you using?

Comment: You need a place to save the submitted data - a server / backend.

Comment: I am using an online RDE (repl.it) and the current for works but it does not save the data