# Is it possible to write data in JSON file without AJAX or backend?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I´m developing an small test app and I had a doubt about JSON in frontend.

I´m working with React and I´m using a JSON file as a small testing DB, saving only 1 user. The fact is that I want to write more users there and edit the JSON registers.

Is that possible without backend or AJAX?

**EDIT: **

I´m using localStorage for the actual logged in user and it´s moves, at the end need to save it´s data before I close session and localStorage loses.

Comment: Without Ajax, yes, backend no

Comment: There are numerous cloud data storage services you can use

Comment: When you close the browser or the tab, the data inside localStorage should not be lost. Be sure to use localStorage and not sessionStorage

Comment: Oh true, I missed something in the edit, when I close session I clean the localStorage data, using it as a login "flag"

Comment: @charlietfl the fact is that I need only front-end without external services

Comment: Many are free and take next to no time to set up for  test app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is used for HTTP requests between a front-end (ex: ReactJS, VueJS) and a back-end (ex: NodeJS/Express, Python/Flask).

If you're using a JSON variable, the data will be deleted everytime the website refreshes. If you're using a JSON file, you can't access the file system from the browser for security reasons.

What I recommend to use is **localStorage**, which acts as a local database for front-end ONLY **per browser** (per user).
The most common usage is:

The setter:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 'John')
```

The getter:

```
const name = localStorage.getItem('name');
console.log(name) // John
```

In React, you could set and update data as the following in this example I made:

**DEMO** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fctts3

Comment: Thanks for the answer @josemartindev, the fact is that I should use Redux for this things, but honestly I don´t know how to use it (need to study it). 

The fact is that I´m only developing frontend on this test and I need something to save the data, create new users and modify their values.

Comment: Before learning Redux, try first using React's state + localStorage. When you modify state, save in localStorage as well. Be sure to set state and set localStorage before entering components as well (using useEffect or componentDidMount)

Comment: The fact is what I´ve updated in my question, I´m using localStorage, but I need to create more users and modify their datas (something simple, plain data) I´m also using states but I didn´t get it at all .

Comment: @josemartindev your answer is the closest to the fact I want to get, but still looking for an answer

Comment: @B2DAW When you say **"Save data before I close session"**, to save this data you actually NEED a back end in order to save the data in a JSON file or in a Database, because with React you can't access the file system.

Comment: @josemartindev you´re right, I will save it all in localStorage, is the easiest solution, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no. you can't write data directly to client's disk.
but there are workarounds.
one way is using common browsers storage options. such as **localstorage**:

```
localStorage.setItem(keyname, value)
```

[read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_setitem.asp)

another way **if you need to move the data** is to make the user **download** your file, and save it. when you need it again they can re-upload it to your front-end page. you can read up on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016088/10168988).

of course there are other options like **cookies** and **IndexedDB**/**WebSQL**. but I think **local storage** can do just fine for your needs.

EDIT:
if you don't have problem with having an internet connection, there is also the awesom option of using google sheets as a database! using this tool:
https://sheety.co/