# React Native how to write an Object to file (JSON) in project directory for Debugging

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am sort of losing my mind at this. I simply want to write to a JSON file at runtime while debugging my app. I have a redux store state I want to view cleanly in a file while I debug, so I figured I would simply export/write the object to a file.

I am now realizing this is way more confusing to do than I thought, as I cannot simply use `Node.js` and `fs.writeFile()`

Why is this so complicated, and what can I do? If writing to a file on my project directory is not possible, how else can I cleanly view the state of my redux store? console logging the state is way too messy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use fs.writeFile() because that is a server-side function and react native is client-side.

What you can do is console log it to terminal.

You can also stringify it and send it as a query parameter to your server and write code to process it.

Or you can send it in the request body of a post request and write code to handle that request body.