# Write a file on local disk from web app (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

I'm developing a web app using ReactJS and trying to create a txt file with a number in it on the local storage, c:\temp for example.

Is it possible to do it without keep asking the user for his approval (dialog)?

Thanks

Comment: No, as far as I know, the only way to write a file to the disk is to download it, and it requires user's approval. Browsers would never allow JS to silently write a file to the disk, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: You can't store directly on a users drive, but you can use the File & Directory API, this creates a virtual file system were you could store text files without constantly asking the user.  More info here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction  Of course if it's just txt files you might find localeStorage will be just as good, but the File / Directory API gives you that classic File / Directory feel.. :)

Answer (score 1):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is a browser API and not an arbitrary file on the user's disk. If you are going to use it, then there is a [handy React hook for it](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/).

You can't write to arbitrary files on the user's disk, although you can generate [a download from in-memory data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63365961/19068). This may be saved to the user's download folder or may prompt a SaveAs dialog (you can't control which).

If you want to store data on the server then you can make HTTP requests to it (i.e. use Ajax) and write a web service to process those requests.