# How to read and write JSON with Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I want to read a json, save it in an array and after doing changes to said array, replace the information in the json with the new information in the array.

I have this model

```
export class User{
 id : number
 name:string
}
```

The json that I am using called users.json

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John"
 }
]
```

I have this in a service

```
http=inject(HttpClient)
userList : User[]=new Array <User>()
```

I tried using an HttpClient, which can read the file fine, but I don't know how to pass it to the array, nor do I know how to write in it.

```
this.http.get("../assets/users.json").subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

```
this.http.put("../assets/users.json").subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

How can I use these methodts to read and write? I don't truly undertand the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to read from a file, not actually make HTTP requests.  Here's how I've done similar things.

You already have a file on disk, so you can import that using something like:

```
import USERS_JSON from '../assets/users.json';
const USERS: User[] = USERS_JSON as User[];
```

You have to be careful though; if you add methods to your class, when you convert the JSON to objects, you'll be missing the methods and you'll get strange errors later.  It took me a long time to figure that out.  I now import JSON into interfaces that are "data only/DTO" and then create the class objects indirectly from there.

Comment: I guess I just now noticed that you want to write the file back out, but I don't think you can write to a file on the file system due to security issues.  This question talks a little bit about that... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript