# FileReader() support in HTAs

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, hta

Does anyone know if HTAs support FileReader() when IE10 or IE11 are installed?

Example:
    var reader = new FileReader();

I'm getting "Object doesn't support this action" but FileReader() is supported on IE10 and IE11, so shouldn't it be available on HTAs too?

Thanks,

Mario

Comment: Maybe you've a [version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519) issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have this flag, try adding it to your HTA:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

If other things fail, you can drop back to the windows API to read/write files:

[Javascript in html write to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795357/javascript-in-html-write-to-file/14796133#14796133)