# Locally Store Variables js

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

When I write code, I do so for my own amusement. I don't upload to a server or have my own website. I recently wrote a code which has quite a long run time (on average) and was just wondering if there's any way I can locally store a variable or two, without the use of cookies or other methods for storing info on a server.
For example:

```
// On first run, declare variable
var rise=0;
// Do something with it when the page is open
setInterval('rise++;',10);
// And then store the value somehow when I close the browser
browser.onClose(locallyStore('keyname',rise));
```

So that when I refresh the page or come back to it another day, the old value will be plugged back in and it will continue running from where I left off...

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working under Windows, you may want to consider an `HTA` file.

These are basicly web-pages that run with application level access and can do some amazing things.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795357/javascript-in-html-write-to-file/14796133#14796133) I cover how to read and write local files.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.keyname = rise;`

Later...

`var rise = localStorage.keyname;`

In any modern browser. (IE9+ if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

$var myItem = localStorage.getItem("key", "value");
```