# How to update text in .txt file which is opened from $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, phonejs

I can read/open it but don't know how to update the specific value in it.

My `data.txt` is like

```
[
  {"slot": "1", "name": "Bob"},
  {"slot": "2", "name": "John"}
]
```

then i want to update it like query the database `"UPDATE data.txt SET name='James' WHERE slot=2"`

After update, I want `data.txt` to be like

```
[
   {"slot": "1", "name": "Bob"},
   {"slot": "2", "name": "James"}
]
```

How can I do this with javascript, Ajax, Jquery

Comment: why using the extension .txt and not .json?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795357/javascript-in-html-write-to-file .. about the logic of the update and the structure of the text, you have to implement it manually in js

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a flat file, you need some form of REST-type interface that allows you to query and update the file, I suggest you switch to a database; seeing as you already seem to know how to do it if it was a database.

Comment: I use it to store the data while my application is in offline mode. so i cannot use the database.